# MongoDB Projection of a subdocument

Tags: mongodb

How do I project the author's first name using a MongoDB query

```
{
 name: "Wings Of Fire",
 author:
 {
  first: "Abdul",
  last: "Kalam"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the field selector to project subdocument fields.  In the shell:

```js
db.test.find({}, {'author.first': 1})
```

Comment: $project can also be used. `db.test.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":1,"author.first":1}}])`